# Fastboot system flashing error

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod, fastboot

### When I try to flash via fastboot system.img to YU Yuphoria I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\New folder\Yu_Yuphoria_YU5010_V2_V2_12.10.12\Firmware>fastboot -i 0x2A96 flash system system.img
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.018s]
sending sparse 'system' 1/4 (261218 KB)...
OKAY [  8.737s]
writing 'system' 1/4...
***FAILED (remote: flash write failure)***
finished. total time: 9.167s
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted here: http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try changing USB wire and make sure you are using USB2 and not USB3